# Why is my rotation reversed in 2.91?

Tags: 3d-view, axis

For some reason, now that I've installed 2.91, all of my rotations are reversed. If I press <kbd>R</kbd> and type a number, it goes counter-clockwise. The angles in the *Properties Panel* <kbd>N</kbd> are also flipped. When I try to rotate and snap to a vertex, it's like the part I'm rotating gets mirrored. I've tried to show all of thse problems in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFd6MtIycpE

Answer (score 2):

Because, to be blunt, the devs frigging broke the behaviour of the rotate operator AGAIN. A fix has been committed so it should be reverted in the next hot fix. https://developer.blender.org/rBf9e994d0f463abb87761591e30c47a9613be6cca